# Finding a closed form for a discrete sum using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider this sum: for context sake, the summand appears in the counting of the possible ways to have one cigarette box empty and the other having left N cigarettes when both boxes start with N cigarettes in the Banach cigarette problem ; so there is a combinatorial explanation which I do not consider here.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N} \binom{2N-i}{N} 2^i = 2^{2N} $$

I wish to know how one would go about finding this closed form using generating functions. More precisely, how would you evaluate

$$ \sum_{N \geq i} \binom{2N-i}{N} x^N $$

Thanks!

Comment: Your two sums don't match. In this on purpose?

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate for math.se. It seems to have nothing to do with computer science.

Comment: The second sum appears when considering $ \sum_{N \geq 0} x^N \sum_{i=0}^N \binom{2N-i}{N} 2^i $
This does not seem to be the way to go, as Andrej has shown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $t_N = {2 N - i \choose N} x^N$ of the sum is [*hypergoemtric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_identity) ($t_{N+1}/t_N$ is a rational function of $N$) which means that the closed form of the sum can be found using [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm), if it exists and is hypergeometric.

When I run the algorithm with Mathematica it says
$$x^i \cdot {}_2F_1(\frac{i+1}{2}, \frac{i+2}{2}; i+1; 4 x)$$
where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). This means that a closed form of the kind you are expecting does not exist.

**Supplemental:**

Gosper's algorithm computes
$$\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{2 n-i}{n} 2^i = 4^n$$
and then
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^n \sum _{i=0}^n \binom{2 n-i}{n} 2^i = \frac{1}{1 - 4 x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but now I realize it was poorly worded as the second sum came out of nowhere...

Comment: Well, the new sums are easier to compute.